# Count of records for multiple tables

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, union

I have 3 tables city,account,alarm in my database.
I want the count of records in the tables individually with date.

ex:

| table_name | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alarm | 26-04-2024 | 5346 |
| alarm | 25-04-2024 | 6766 |
| city | 26-04-2024 | 5346 |
| city | 25-04-2024 | 6766 |
| account | 26-04-2024 | 5346 |
| account | 25-04-2024 | 6766 |

I tried to use this query, but it throws an error

```
select 
    (select count(*) 
     from "table_name" 
     group by to_date(ingest_time)) as city,
    (select count(*) 
     from "table_name" 
     group by to_date(ingest_time)) as alarm
 from dual;
```

Error:

> Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: Both subqueries should not return more than a single row, and it seems they do.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: is this Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `union` three queries (one for each table):

```
select 'Alarm' table_name, date(ingest_time) ingest_date, count(*) cnt from alarm group by date(ingest_time) 
union all 
select 'City',    date(ingest_time), count(*) from city    group by date(ingest_time) 
union all 
select 'Account', date(ingest_time), count(*) from account group by date(ingest_time)
```

Note that all three subqueries must return the same set of columns, with matching datatypes.

Comment: thank you very much. That worked as expected.